# How does okta verify codes work without internet?

Tags: okta, multi-factor-authentication

We use okta verify for MFA. I am attempting to login to okta enabled website in laptop. To get a push notification to approve, I need internet in my mobile device with okta app. But there is an option of enter a code as well. The code was generated in mobile phone without internet and accepted by website as well. Could you please explain how does okta verify codes work without internet?

Comment: TOTP? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_one-time_password

Comment: @msbit thanks for the lead. Very interesting.